# Want to post data from an Android app to rails web-app which uses Devise for authentication

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an existing Rails app which uses Devise to handle authentication.  The app works fine in the browser.

I want a user on the phone to be able to sign into the app and post data into a form.  This requires the authentication_token, however when I sign-in with JSON the response does not include this.

What setting do I need to change in initialisers/devise.rb to get the authentication token?

Antony

Comment: Will the token be in the headers of the response?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know how to get the cookies from a json request eigther. 
I have done something similar a while back but with yaml.
This is what i did to get the token. (i replaced text/yaml by application/json. again donno if it works, but it might be worth a shot.

```
  try {
     data = "--- \nusername: " + name + "\n" + "password: " + password;
     URL myserver = new URL(server + "wannabe");
     URLConnection con = myserver.openConnection();
     con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
     con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*, */*");
     con.setDoOutput(true);
     OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
     out.write(data);
     out.flush();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(
             con.getInputStream()));
     String decode;
     while ((decode = in.readLine()) != null){
       output += decode;
     }
     out.close();
     in.close();
  } catch(IOException e){
    throw new TokenException("Wrong Username/password");
  }
  //Stripping begin and end quotes
  return output.substring(1, output.length() -1);
```